# How can I change fluxcd automatic sync time?

Tags: fluxcd

As we know, fluxcd can check the git reposiroty and docker image repository periodly, and apply the newest changes in the repository.  But how can I control how long it will take to check the change ?  The default time may be ~5 minutes,  if I want to change to 1 minutes, how can I change it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### FluxCD v1

For FluxCD v1, the interval times are controlled by flags on the flux deployment.

There are 2 flags that Control how often Flux syncs the cluster with git.

`--git-poll-interval` controls how often flux looks at Git for new commits.
This value is `git.pollInterval` in the flux helm chart.

`--sync-interval` controls how often flux will apply what’s in git to the cluster, regardless of new commits. This is how, for example, a resource deleted using other means will be re-created.
In the flux helm chart, this value is `sync.interval`, and defaults to the `git.pollInterval` time.

---

#### FluxCD V2

For FluxCD v2, the GitOps Toolkit, the "git poll interval" is controlled by the GitRepository resource for each Git repo defined.

```yaml
apiVersion: source.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta1
kind: GitRepository
metadata:
  name: my-app-repo
  namespace: flux-system
spec:
  interval: 1m # Interval
  url: https://github.com/my-org/my-repo.git
  ref:
    branch: master
```

In Flux v2, the "sync interval" equivalent is referred to in the Kustomization reconciliation.
This is the interval at which you want to undo manual changes.

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
metadata:
  name: my-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  interval: 15m
  path: "./deploy/prod"
  prune: true
  sourceRef:
    kind: GitRepository
    name: my-app-repo
```

Comment: thanks, you saved me lot of research time. Not much about it is written online!

Answer (score 0):

on all relevant Resources you have the `interval` parameter. Here the interval is 30 seconds For example:

```
apiVersion: source.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta1
kind: GitRepository
metadata:
  name: podinfo
  namespace: flux-system
spec:
  interval: 30s
  ref:
    branch: master
  url: https://github.com/your/repostiory
```